# Why is this configuration for ESLint in Visual Studio 2017 not working?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, eslint

I am currently wondering, why ESLint is not working in my project in Visual Studio 2017. There is the file ".eslintrc" in the project-root:

```
{
"extends": "defaults/configurations/eslint",
"env": {
    "browser": true
},
"globals": {
    "xhr": true
},
"rules": {
    "eqeqeq": [ "error", "always", { "null": "ignore" } ]
}
}
```

If I remove the line with "eqeqeq", everything is working fine. But as soon as I add this line, no errors will be displayed at all.

Question 1: Is there any way to see an error-message about the issue ESLint obviously has?

Question 2 as a fallback: What is the issue with this line?

Comment: I think, I found the issue: in VS2017, only numbers are allowed. "eqeqeq": 2 works fine. Unfortunately, this does not allow any detailed configuration...

Comment: Try `"eqeqeq": [2, "always", {  "null": "ignore" }]`. Older versions of ESLint used number to configure warning level before we added "off"/"warning"/"error", so maybe the VS2017 version hasn't been updated.

Comment: @btmills: Tried that, it did not help. `"eqeqeq": [ 2 ]` is still working, `"eqeqeq": [ 2, "always" ]` and your version are not.

Comment: I just found the version-number, if it helps. If I'm not mistaken, VS 2017 uses version 2.0.0 (released 2016-02-12).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to btmills I took a dive into the sources and found the version: VS 2017 uses ESLint 2.0.0 (released 2016-02-12).

The correct configuration is:

```
"eqeqeq": [ 2, "allow-null" ]
```

Documentation is available here:

- [Getting started](http://eslint.org/docs/2.0.0/user-guide/getting-started)
- [Rules](http://eslint.org/docs/2.0.0/rules/)

The links from the error-list in VS 2017 lead to the current documentation, where you can find many features that do not work in version 2.0.0.